# jq: error: canonical/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1. Not able to read \ in json using jq

Tags: json, syntax, key, jq

```json
{
    "labels": {
                    "chart": "boss",
                    "heritage": "back",
                    "istio": "gw",
                    "released": "istio",
                    "service.istio.io/canonical-name": "istio"
                }
}
```

This is my json. I would like to read the below key value using jq.
.labels.released : i am getting the value of istio.

similarly
i would like to read "service.istio.io/canonical-name" this key. But getting the error of
jq: error: canonical/0 is not defined at , line 1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq '.labels["service.istio.io/canonical-name"]'
```